# How can i set 2 same width div in span9 class div in twitter bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

i want to set 2 same width div in span9 class div, like below:

```
<div class="span9">

<!--i want these 2 div with same width -->
<div>
Content goes here
</div>

<div>
Content goes here
</div>

</div>
<!--span9 ends -->
```

What is the best practice to achieve this.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Using `row-fluid.` we can nest equal width columns inside `span9`

[Jsfiddle with nested divs](http://jsfiddle.net/shail/HpmHZ/4/show)

```
<div class="row-fluid ">
<div class="span9">Span9
    <div class="row-fluid ">
        <div class="span6">Span 6</div>
        <div class="span6">Span 6</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="span3">Span 3</div>
</div>
```